# How to get last inserted all records in mysql

Tags: mysql

Actually I don't know how to get last inserted records in two table.

I want to get last recently inserted all records in table.

I used LAST_INSERT_ID() function but it gives only one last record and i want multiple records in table.

Comment: what library are you using to perform the query? provide the code you are using to perform the query

Comment: SELECT  * from tblname order by id DESC LIMIT 0,n

Comment: That's what `LAST_INSERT_ID()` does. Your title: *"How to get last inserted all records in mysql"* contradicts what you're asking.

Comment: *"I want to get last recently inserted all records in table."* --- *"and i want multiple records in table."* - Run a `SELECT` after the `INSERT`.

Comment: Show your code so we can see what you are doing. Perhaps you are using `multi_query`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to get all records using LAST_INSERT_ID(), which can give only last inserted record, you can't get second last inserted record with adding any extra where clause or something like that. Either you could fetch all record directly or you can get last insert id first then fetch all (other) record based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into this myself right now and the only way I can come up with is to retrieve the number of affected rows from the most recent query, and then select that many  rows from the table, with the selection ordered by ID (or whatever is most appropriate to your use case) in Descending order, thus:

The insertion query:

```
INSERT INTO db.table (id,var1,var2) 
VALUES 
  (NULL,'value1','value2')
  (NULL,'value3','value4')
  (NULL,'value5','value6')
```

Use mysql_affected_rows() to retrieve how many rows were inserted.

(In PHP this would be $number = $mysqli_object->affected_rows - your code implementation may differ)

then fetch the rows using that value as the LIMIT value:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $number
```

Ideally you'd wrap that up in a method or function dependant on your coding and use case.